# What Qt container class to use for a sorted list?

Tags: qt, list

Part of my application involves rendering audio waveforms. The user will be able to zoom in/out of the waveform. Starting at fully zoomed-out, I only want to sample the audio at the necessary internals to draw the waveform at the given resolution. Then, when they zoom in, asynchronously resample the "missing points" and provide a clearer waveform. (Think Google Maps.) I'm not sure the best data structure to use in Qt world. Ideally, I would like to store data samples sorted by time, but with the ability to fill-in points as needed.

So, for example, the data points might initially look like:

```
data[0 ms] = 10
data[10 ms] = 32
data[20 ms] = 21
...
```

But when they zoom in, I would get more points as necessary, perhaps:

```
data[0 ms] = 10
data[2 ms] = 11
data[4 ms] = 18
data[6 ms] = 30
data[10 ms] = 32
data[20 ms] = 21
...
```

Note that the values in brackets are lookup values (milliseconds), not array indices.

I should be able to efficiently query for a range ("all points between 10 and 30 milliseconds") and somewhat-efficiently insert new points.

In .Net I might have used a `SortedList<int, int>`. What would be the best class to use in Qt? Or should I use a STL container?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

QMap is automatically sorted, so iterating over it will produce a sorted (ascending) list.

It also provides Qmap::upperBound() and QMap::lowerBound() which you can use for your range finding functionality.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html

Comment: When iterating over a QHash, the items are arbitrarily ordered. With QMap, the items are always sorted **by key**.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly advice you to have a look here : [Generic Containers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html)

You'll find a good summary of different container classes in Qt... I would also recommend you to use one of those ! Looks to me you could use a QMap !

Hope it helps a bit !

Answer (score -1):

> What would be the best class to use in Qt? Or should I use a STL container?

You can use the std::map. I recommend to use STL containers for the business logic, and Qt containers only when it's needed for binding data to your GUI.

EDIT: changed std::set to std::map

Comment: I strongly disagree with using STL over QT. By using STL you're going to be loosing some really nice QT features like shallow copies. And then you're going to have to convert to QT objects to pass the data to the GUI, and this can cause deep copies. And (according to the Qt Developers) STL still isn't 100% compatible across all the platforms Qt supports.